# Find 2nd Most Recent Date SQL with JOINS

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to return the second most recent date for a set of projects in SQL, but I'm getting the error 'Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.'
Here is my code:

```
 SELECT ProjectId, max(CreatedDateTime)
     FROM NTNote.dbo.nProjectReference P                                    
     INNER JOIN NTNote.dbo.nJournal J                                   
        ON J.JournalID = P.JournalID
        Where CreatedDateTime < (SELECT max(CreatedDateTime), projectid
        FROM NTNote.dbo.nProjectReference P                                 
          INNER JOIN NTNote.dbo.nJournal J                                  
             ON J.JournalID = P.JournalID
          Group by ProjectId)
        Group by ProjectId
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the below code for desired output ( sql server).

```
with cte_grp
as
 (SELECT ProjectId,CreatedDateTime,ROW_NUMBER () OVER(PARTITION BY ProjectId ORDER BY CreatedDateTime desc) RNo
     FROM NTNote.dbo.nProjectReference P                                    
     INNER JOIN NTNote.dbo.nJournal J                                   
        ON J.JournalID = P.JournalID)

        SELECT *
        FROM cte_grp
        WHERE RNO=2
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Row_Number() over (partition by ProjectId order by CreatedDateTime desc) as rownum
```

and use 2 as predicate to get the output.